# Complile error OpenH264 using Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, h.264

I am trying to compile the openh264 project for android but facing some trouble.
I have setup the android_ndk-r10 properly and able to compile sample apps provided with the ndk.

Here's what i've done till now. Downloaded the zip of openh264 from here https://github.com/cisco/openh264.
Navigated to the openh264-openh264v1.1\codec\build\android\dec\jni path using the cmd prompt and then fired the ndk-build command.
It starts the build process but throws error while building libs for both encoder and decoder. Following is the error while building encoder lib....

```
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: welsencdemo <= welsenc.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: welsencdemo <= read_config.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: welsencdemo <= myjni.cpp
[armeabi] Prebuilt       : libstlport_shared.so <= <NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/stlport
/libs/armeabi/thumb/
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libwelsencdemo.so
D:/Softwares/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windo
ws-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-android
eabi/bin/ld.exe: D:/Work/Android/OpenH264/openh264-openh264v1.1/codec/build/andr
oid/enc//obj/local/armeabi/objs/welsencdemo/__/__/__/__/console/enc/src/welsenc.
o: in function CreateSVCEncHandle(ISVCEncoder**):D:/Work/Android/OpenH264/openh2
64-openh264v1.1/codec/build/android/enc//jni/../../../../console/enc/src/welsenc
.cpp:931: error: undefined reference to 'WelsCreateSVCEncoder'
D:/Softwares/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windo
ws-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-android
eabi/bin/ld.exe: D:/Work/Android/OpenH264/openh264-openh264v1.1/codec/build/andr
oid/enc//obj/local/armeabi/objs/welsencdemo/__/__/__/__/console/enc/src/welsenc.
o: in function DestroySVCEncHandle(ISVCEncoder*):D:/Work/Android/OpenH264/openh2
64-openh264v1.1/codec/build/android/enc//jni/../../../../console/enc/src/welsenc
.cpp:937: error: undefined reference to 'WelsDestroySVCEncoder'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [D:/Work/Android/OpenH264/openh264-openh264v1.1/codec/build/androi
d/enc//obj/local/armeabi/libwelsencdemo.so] Error 1
```

Similarly while building the decoder lib facing an error as below....

```
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: welsdecdemo <= h264dec.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: welsdecdemo <= read_config.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: welsdecdemo <= d3d9_utils.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: welsdecdemo <= myjni.cpp
[armeabi] Prebuilt       : libstlport_shared.so <= <NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/stlport
/libs/armeabi/thumb/
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libwelsdecdemo.so
D:/Softwares/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windo
ws-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-android
eabi/bin/ld.exe: D:/Work/Android/OpenH264/openh264-openh264v1.1/codec/build/andr
oid/dec//obj/local/armeabi/objs/welsdecdemo/__/__/__/__/console/dec/src/h264dec.
o: in function DecMain(int, char**):D:/Work/Android/OpenH264/openh264-openh264v1
.1/codec/build/android/dec//jni/../../../../console/dec/src/h264dec.cpp:417: err
or: undefined reference to 'WelsCreateDecoder'
D:/Softwares/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windo
ws-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-android
eabi/bin/ld.exe: D:/Work/Android/OpenH264/openh264-openh264v1.1/codec/build/andr
oid/dec//obj/local/armeabi/objs/welsdecdemo/__/__/__/__/console/dec/src/h264dec.
o: in function DecMain(int, char**):D:/Work/Android/OpenH264/openh264-openh264v1
.1/codec/build/android/dec//jni/../../../../console/dec/src/h264dec.cpp:447: err
or: undefined reference to 'WelsDestroyDecoder'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [D:/Work/Android/OpenH264/openh264-openh264v1.1/codec/build/androi
d/dec//obj/local/armeabi/libwelsdecdemo.so] Error 1
```

Before trying to build I did not make any changes to the openh264 code that I downloaded. Its a linking error, I tried to fix by making changes to the welsdecdemo.mk file that refers to the .h and .cpp files that are available in the code, but still getting the same error. As am a java developer and new with NDK and cpp am facing a tough time.
Request your help, with some useful pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mstorsjo I could successfully compile the openh264 libs and also run the android decoder/encoder sample app. The decoding/encoding works great.

The steps to compile the OpenH264 project(using windows) for Android are as mentioned by mstorsjo :-

You need 
1) [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) 
2) android-ndk 
3) [OpenH264](https://github.com/cisco/openh264) project

Then from within MSYS, do "make OS=android NDKROOT=/unix/path/to/ndk TARGET=9 libopenh264.so". Now you can build the sample projects in codec/build/android just as you tried to do before.

Once the OpenH264 project is built then follow the steps I mentioned in my original question to build the sample android apps for decoder/encoder.

Comment: Hi, have you got working example of openh264 on android?

Answer (score 0):

Please see README.md in OpenH264 for instructions on how to build it for android.

The android project that you've found in codec\build\android\dec only builds a test example of a decoder - it doesn't build the codec itself. The main makefile in the root of the project (which README.md describes how to use) will both build the codec itself and the test examples.

Comment: I am afraid am not able to comprehend the readme.md file. I am completely new to this, is it possible to compile the codec using windows? Is android-ndk itself sufficient to compile the codec? Any links from where i can study how to compile such projects?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to compile it for android under windows (I've seen people discuss it but I haven't tried myself). android-ndk is the most vital component, but you also need "make". (There's a make binary in the ndk that you might try to use.) The key part from the readme is, from the "For Android Builds" section: make OS=android NDKROOT=**ANDROID_NDK** TARGET=**ANDROID_TARGET**. If you use make from the ndk, you could do something like this (untested) at the root directory of the project: `\path\to\ndk\prebuilt\windows-x86\bin\make OS=android NDKROOT=\path\to\ndk TARGET=9`

Comment: The prebuilt make doesn't seem to be enough, you probably need to have msys, and even then there's currently an issue in the openh264/android platform makefile that causes issues on windows.

Comment: Ok, so with the current state, you need 1) MSYS 2) android-ndk 3) this change: https://github.com/cisco/openh264/pull/1270 (hopefully soon merged). Then from within MSYS, do "make OS=android NDKROOT=/unix/path/to/ndk TARGET=9 libopenh264.so". Now you can build the sample projects in codec/build/android just as you tried to do before.

Comment: Thanks to you (mstorsjo) I could successfully compile the openh264 libs and also run the android decoder/encoder sample. The decoding works great and now trying encoding. Figuring out the .cfg file that needs to be provided as input to the encoder....