# ndk version [] not compatible with openh264

Tags: github, android-ndk, clone, openh264

I installed https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android , got the SDK,NDK etc, now i get this error when i run $ make :

```
cat: /usr/local/bin/RELEASE.TXT: No such file or directory
(standard_in) 1: parse error
cat: /usr/local/bin/RELEASE.TXT: No such file or directory
Makefile:78: *** ndk version [] not compatible with openh264..  Stop.
```

Can some one help me please?(I installed all i need with using brew and i am on Mac OSX)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25243003/complile-error-openh264-using-android-ndk ?